# Is there any way to know which table contain the specific entry while searching multiple tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have multiple tables in a database. I'm searching all the tables for a specific entry. The search result returns correctly. But how do i know which table contains that specific data/entry in MySql? Is there any way to return/know the table name that contains the specific entry while searching multiple tables?

```
Dim statusQuery As String = $"SELECT * FROM management.hostelA,management.hostelB,management.hostelC,management.hostelD where hostelA.occupant1='{stu_name.Text}' or hostelA.occupant2='{stu_name.Text}' or hostelB.occupant1='{stu_name.Text}' or hostelB.occupant2='{stu_name.Text}' or hostelC.occupant1='{stu_name.Text}' or hostelC.occupant2='{stu_name.Text}' or hostelD.occupant1='{stu_name.Text}' or hostelD.occupant2='{stu_name.Text}'"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(statusQuery, con)
Dim sdr As MySqlDataReader
sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
While sdr.Read
   statusflag = statusflag + 1
End While
```

I want to know which table contains the stu_name.text

Comment: Could you please post your SQL query?

Comment: How are you performing the search? Are you using a tool or a query?

Comment: How would you not know which table you're searching? If it is just a bunch of UNIONs, tack on a string field to each sub union result with the table name being queried.

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design

Comment: @Uueerdo The OP could be using third party software to search for text

Comment: mysqldump  ... > Db-dump and then search in the file. Maybe it's a poor solution but it works

Comment: That is a very very very bad query. You're not querying "the tables in the comma separated list", you're querying the cartesian product of those tables. _(If each of those tables have 100 rows, you are checking 100000000 result row candidates; and if the text is only in one table, you'll still/"only" get 1000000 final result rows.)_ _Edit: oh, I see Bill already addressed this...leaving comment for the numerical example stressing the problem with the query._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off querying each table individually, i.e. one table at a time. Then you will easily see which table the name was found in.

Despite the comment from @Uueerdo, you're not doing a bunch of `UNION` operations, you're doing a bunch of `JOIN` operations. This means your query is doing a huge [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of four tables. In other words, every row of all four tables is matched to every row of all other tables. I'm sure this is not what you intended.

You need to learn SQL before you try to do things like this.

Until then, you should query the tables one at a time.